# Allow only .xls and .xlsx file in file upload using <input type=“file”>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to validate .xls and .xlsx files only. If any other file has been given, it should give an errror message. (example:file_name.exe.xls). How do I validate it through jquery?

Comment: There is a way to do it. It's by writing some code :)

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary maje le rahe ho

Comment: @atulquest93 ab aur kya bol sakte hain.. pehle efforts toh daalna hain na inhe.. tabto kuch baat banega inka

Comment: @atulquest93  i chequed reference link and i tested with file_name.exe.jpg   still it is taking the input..it is not giving error message

Comment: @balachandra check this `https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/QWQdz/`

Comment: @atulquest93  i tried the above link still no luck. when i uploading this extension (notepad.exe%00.jpg), it is giving success message.but it is a .exe file it must not accept.Any help Appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In java i can do it like String name = "notepad.exe%00.jpg";

  if (name.contains(".exe")) {
   System.out.println("error");
  } else {
   System.out.println("success");
  }

Comment: the above program how to do it in javascript or jquery